# Can we add the same element twice in a python list?

Tags: python, list

Here is the question:

> Here is an array of length M with numbers in the range 1 ... N, where
>   N is less than or equal to 20. We are to go through it and count how
>   many times each number is encountered. I.e. it is like Vowel Count
>   task, but we need to maintain more than one counter. Be sure to use
>   separate array for them, do not create a lot of separate variables,
>   one for each counter.
>
> Input data contain M and N in the first line. The second (rather long)
>   line will contain M numbers separated by spaces. Answer should contain
>   exactly N values, separated by spaces. First should give amount of
>   1-s, second - amount of 2-s and so on.
>
> Example:
>
> data input: 10 3 3 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 3
>
> answer: 5 2 3

Here is my code for this problem:

```
# 10 3
# 3 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 3

# [1, 0, 0]
# expected: [5, 2, 3]



# Transfer the first line input into number lista:
rawone = input()
stringa = rawone.split()
lista = []
for el in stringa:
    lista.append(int(el))
# check the function:
# print (lista)
# Transfer the second line input into number listb:
rawtwo = input()
stringb = rawtwo.split()
listb = []
for ele in stringb:
    listb.append(int(ele))
# check the function:
# print (listb)

# initiate a few variables:
t = 0 # the current time
times = lista[1] # the total time
print (times)
d = 1 # detect key
n = 0 # the number of qualified candidate
out = [] # the list of output
elist = []


# method: while (t<times) --> for element in listo: if (el==d) --> n=n+1:

# THIS PART HAS SOME PROBLEMS!!!
while t < times:
    n = 0 # reinitiate the n
    for elem in listb: # ***WHY THIS FOR LOOP CAN ONLY BE EXCUTE ONCE AND NOT WORK ANY MORE???
        if elem == d:
            elist += [(elem)]
        d = d + 1
    out.append(len(elist))
    print (elist)

    t = t + 1

print (out)
```

So I have some problem with the formula part and it's not what I expect it would do. And I checked my answer. I am confused why it only add one qualified element in each turn. How can I fix this? Thank you for your generous help!

So the problem has been solved, my final code is like below:

```
# Transfer the first line input into number lista:
rawone = input()
stringa = rawone.split()
lista = []
for el in stringa:
    lista.append(int(el))
# check the function:
# print (lista)
# Transfer the second line input into number listb:
rawtwo = input()
stringb = rawtwo.split()
listb = []
for ele in stringb:
    listb.append(int(ele))
# check the function:
# print (listb)

# initiate a few variables:
t = 0 # the current time
times = lista[1] # the total time
# print (times)
d = 1 # detect key
n = 0 # the number of qualified candidate
out = [] # the list of output
elist = []


# method: while (t<times) --> for element in listo: if (el==d) --> n=n+1:

# THIS PART HAS SOME PROBLEMS!!!
while t < times:
    n = 0 # reinitiate the n
    for elem in listb: # ***WHY THIS FOR LOOP CAN ONLY BE EXCUTE ONCE AND NOT WORK ANY MORE???
        if elem == d:
            elist.append(elem)
    d = d + 1
    out.append(len(elist))
    elist = [] # reinitiate elist
    # print (elist)

    t = t + 1
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in out))
```

Comment: I don't understand how the title of the question relates to the question.

Comment: The answer to the question title is "yes". A hint to the code: use meaningful variables (not `lista`, `listb`, `elist` and so on) and you don't have to do the outer loop, just one pass over the actual numbers (`3 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 3`) is enough.

Comment: I have no idea what logic your code is attempting, but since I see `append`s and other stuff, I can tell it's going the wrong way. The obvious way to solve this problem is to start with a list of `0`s, then use the values from the input list as indexes for an increment statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is difficult to follow due to the poor variable names and extra variables.  As you continue in programming, please look for examples of better coding.

The main problem you have is that you increment **d** inside the inner loop.  Take the statement **d = d + 1** and un-indent it one level.  This means that you increment d only once each time you go through the outer **while** loop.

Even better, just use the outer loop for this.  Since you already know how many times you have to execute that, use a **for** loop on the outside, as well:

```
for d in range(1, times+1):
    n = 0   # reinitiate the n
    for elem in listb:  # ***WHY THIS FOR LOOP CAN ONLY BE EXCUTE ONCE AND NOT WORK ANY MORE???
        if elem == d:
            elist += [elem]
    out.append(len(elist))
    print (elist)

print (out)
```

This at least gets you to output closer to what you want:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[5, 7, 10]
```

You can now attack the next problem: counting only the entries for that particular number, rather than all the numbers found so far.  To do this, be sure to clean out the **elist** every time, instead of only once:

```
for d in range(1, times+1):
    elist = []
    for elem in listb:
    ...
```

... which finally gets the output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[5, 2, 3]
```

I expect that you can finish from here.

---

Also note that you can simply set  up **out** as a direct count of the elements you find.  If you find a 1, increment the first element of **out**; if you find a 2, increment the second, and so on.  The code for that segment has no outer loop; it just looks like this:

```
out = [0] * times
for elem in listb:
    out[elem-1] += 1

print (out)
```

That replaces all your code below **print (times)**.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this might not *count* for your assignment, but anyways:

```
from collections import Counter
N = 3
my_list = [3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]

c = Counter(my_list)
print(" ".join(c[i+1] for i in range(N)))
```

Comment: but this *does* count!

Answer (score 0):

@Prune shows you how to fix your code. I also want to show you how it's possible to solve this problem with much less code (using a list rather than resorting to `collections.Counter`)

Since you are given M and N, it's a good idea to store them in variables od those names

```
first_line = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
M, N = first_line
second_line = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Now create a list (array) with N zeros. These are the counters

```
result = [0] * N
```

Remember that list (array) indices start at 0, so we need to subtract `1` from each `elem`

```
for elem in second_line:
    result[elem - 1] += 1
```

Show the result

```
print(result)
```

Comment: Aye I don't understand the method but thank you for your help. I will try to write more simplified code next time.